# Rebuilding search index on CD environment

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm changing my code to use Sitecore.Search from the old Lucene way. To do this, I use the crawler from the [ADC module](http://sitecorian.github.io/SitecoreSearchContrib/). I'm currently not using the Searcher, just the Crawler from the Module (although we're looking to change to that in a later stage).
I've managed to get the indexing and search functionality working perfectly on my CM environment, but the CD environment keeps giving the following error when I try rebuilding:

> Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='core'].

The code I'm running to rebuild the search indexes is on CD is:

```csharp
foreach (var options in from ListItem item in cblIndexes.Items 
                        where item.Selected           
                        select new JobOptions("RebuildSearchIndex", "index", global::Sitecore.Client.Site.Name, new Builder(item.Value), "Rebuild") { AfterLife = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0) })
           {
               JobManager.Start(options);
           }
```

Running this code on CM works fine.
My configuration for one of the failing indexes:

```xml
<search>
      <configuration>
        <indexes>
          <index id="PressReleaseIndex" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <web ref="search/crawlers/PressReleaseIndex" param1="web" />
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
      <crawlers>
        <PressReleaseIndex type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler">
          <Database>$(1)</Database>
          <Root>/sitecore/content/home/newsroom</Root>
          <IndexAllFields>false</IndexAllFields>

          <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <pressrelease>{91DB1CBC-32F8-4344-A974-7F4FE5F07668}</pressrelease>
          </include>

          <include hint="list:IncludeField">
            <title>{F8C6E41E-3C9F-45F6-8409-61F5C8F2BF19}</title>
            <shortdescription>{D25294E9-03C1-4E62-968B-5410AAAD0863}</shortdescription>
            <body>{A0AD83E2-1099-407C-B8D7-C123FDAAD5DD}</body>
            <releasedate>{D0B594BC-2ED6-4A0E-A050-3243CD044040}</releasedate>
          </include>

          <fieldCrawlers hint="raw:AddFieldCrawlers">
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.LookupFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="Droplink" />
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.LookupFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="Droptree" />
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.DateFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="Datetime" />
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.DateFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="Date" />
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.NumberFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="Number" />
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.MultilistFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="Multilist" />
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.MultilistFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="Treelist" />
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.MultilistFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="TreelistEx" />
            <fieldCrawler type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.FieldCrawlers.MultilistFieldCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler" fieldType="Checklist" />
          </fieldCrawlers>

          <dynamicFields hint="raw:AddDynamicFields">
            <dynamicField type="Sapient.Practice.Ccmp.Common.SitecoreSearch.DynamicFields.ReleaseYearField,Sapient.Practice.Ccmp.Common" name="_releaseyear" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
            <dynamicField type="Sapient.Practice.Ccmp.Common.SitecoreSearch.DynamicFields.ReleaseMonthField,Sapient.Practice.Ccmp.Common" name="_releasemonth" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
          </dynamicFields>

          <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldTypes">
            <!-- Text fields need to be tokenized -->
            <fieldType name="single-line text" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
            <fieldType name="multi-line text" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
            <fieldType name="word document" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
            <fieldType name="html" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
            <fieldType name="rich text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
            <fieldType name="memo" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
            <fieldType name="text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
            <fieldType name="date" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
          </fieldTypes>
        </PressReleaseIndex>
```

I've went through the [Staging Guide](http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Products/Web-Content-Management/Content-Management/Multisite-Deployment.aspx) back when the solution was still on Sitecore 6.3.1 (we upgraded to Sitecore 6.5 update 5), and removed all references to the `Core` database.

When I go to my ShowConfig page on CD and look for 'core', I don't find any results. There's also no references to Core database in the AppSettings.config, ConnectionStrings.config or any other config file I've got. As far as I've found I'm also not referencing the Core database hardcoded (or I would've had the issue before that).

I haven't been able to figure out where the Core database would get referenced. 
The complete exception with stacktrace:

```
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.MethodInstance.Invoke()
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='core']
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition, String format, Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Data.LookupSources.GetDatabase(String source)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.CustomField.GetDatabase()
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.DelimitedField.ValidateLinks(LinksValidationResult result)
   at Sitecore.Links.ItemLinks.AddLinks(Field field, List`1 links, ItemLinkState linkState)
   at Sitecore.Links.ItemLinks.GetLinks(ItemLinkState linkState, Boolean allVersions, Boolean includeStandardValuesLinks)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.GetItemLinks(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddSpecialFields(Document document, Item item)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.IndexVersion(Item item, Item latestVersion, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at scSearchContrib.Crawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler.IndexVersion(Item item, Item latestVersion, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddItem(Item item, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.Add(IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Index.Rebuild()
   at Saga.Sitecore.Web.Builder.Rebuild()
```

Comment: Is your CD environment working without core database?

Comment: Yes, it is. This has been done about 2 years ago (and has been working fine), so shouldn't be the cause I'd assume

Comment: Does the CD and CM environments have the same installed .NET framework versions? I.e. does one have 4 and the other 4.5?

Comment: The CD and CM environments are on the same box (the issue is happening on a DEV server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the issue is specifically related to your index configuration. Looking at your stack trace, the exception really stems from the Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Data.LookupSources.GetDatabase method when your search crawler is attempting to get links (references) for a delimited field (multilist, treelist, etc...).

```
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Data.LookupSources.GetDatabase(String source)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.CustomField.GetDatabase()
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.DelimitedField.ValidateLinks(LinksValidationResult result)
   at Sitecore.Links.ItemLinks.AddLinks(Field field, List`1 links, ItemLinkState linkState)
   at Sitecore.Links.ItemLinks.GetLinks(ItemLinkState linkState, Boolean allVersions, Boolean includeStandardValuesLinks)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.GetItemLinks(Item item)
```

Using reflector, we can look at the Sitecore.Data.Fields.CustomField.GetDatabase() method, which calls the LookupSources.GetDatabase method if the associated field has a value in its "Source" field. The LookupSources.GetDatabase method attempts to parse the "Source" field to determine which database to query for source items in the associated delimited field. Some source fields can explicitly set which database to query for source items using the "db=" parameter.

So, long story short, when you use `<IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>` in your index configuration, one of the fields your crawler is attempting to index has a "Source" field containing a reference to the core databasae.

Your solution of setting the `<IndexAllFields />` value to false and then explicitly including or excluding fields to index is certainly valid, but if you want to track down the root cause of the issue you'll likely have to go looking through "Source" fields.

Comment: The recommended practice isn't to have the Core database removed, so I think I'll add that in whenever I get some time, which will get rid of the issue for me as well. 
On a side note, Sitecore Support pointed me to this tool to quickly search for the culprit: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Support_Toolbox.aspx
Haven't had the time to install it yet, but figured I'd drop the link for anyone else who has the same issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to the `<IndexAllFields>` in the configuration. My second index had this set to true. I set it to false, did the `IncludeFields` and `ExcludeFields` and it's now building successfully.

I still wonder why it's throwing that error though, as the `Core` database has been removed earlier. Possibly the standard fields?

Comment: Yes, it could be standard field. In your exception there is Sitecore.Data.Fields.DelimitedField.ValidateLinks and then Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase. Maybe there is some reference to item from core db.